# Why the variable in Stateless widget is still accessible after dispose?

Tags: flutter

In the snippet below, I would like to know why `scaffoldMessenger` is still available in the widget, although this code line:

```
await Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).removeProduct(id);
```

removes the instance of `UserProductItem` from the list of `UserProductItem`?

```dart
    class UserProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
      final String id;
    
      UserProductItem({
        required this.id,
      });
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final scaffoldMessenger = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
        return Container(
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              try {
                await Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).removeProduct(id);
              } on HttpException catch (e) {
                scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Deleting failed!')));
              }
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

To better understand by myself, I've converted this widget from **Stateless** to **Stateful** widget and I see, that after `.removeProduct(id)` method, the `UserProductItem` is disposed, but `scaffoldMessenger` is still available for a call.

`dispose()` method outputs `'disposed'` via `print()` in console, before tackling the `scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar()`.

Does it mean, that after dispose the variables defined in StatelessWidget are still accessible?
How long are they accessible? Should I manually dispose of `scaffoldMessenger` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** The `scaffoldMessenger` gets its `context` object and uses it only once during variable's initialization just to reference the `Scaffold` up in the widget tree.

**Longer explanation:**
During this piece execution:

```
try {
     await Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).removeProduct(id);
     } on HttpException catch (e) {
     scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Deleting failed!')));
}
```

, the context becomes inaccessible, because `dispose()` was called. However, the `scaffoldMessenger` got its `context` object very early, during the `UserProductItem` construction time.
As `scaffoldMessenger` isn't being constructed later in this line:

```
scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Deleting failed!')));
```

(like this: `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)`), it still can use previously referenced object created with `context`, because this object was actually the parent screen's `Scaffold` object, which is still there, despite `UserProductItem`'s disposal. So that's why there's no errors.